# Remote working in Norway

Tags: taxes, social-security, norway, contracts

## Situation

I'm currently contracting under an umbrella company in an EU country and am considering moving to Norway for an as-of-yet still unknown amount of time but likely between 6-12 months.

I intend to keep working for the same client company in the EU while living in Norway and would most likely be required to fly over on a regular basis, let's say for a 1 week every 2 months.

My client company has a registered branch in Norway with offices in the country.

## Assumptions

1. Since Norway is in the EEA, I'm an EU citizen and according [to this SO](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17379/can-eu-citizens-work-in-iceland), I understand I can work there for any length of time without a visa or residency permit.
2. I would assume contract options in Norway are:

   - employee (permanent)
   - contractor (employee)
   - contractor (director)

## Questions

1. Would I need to register with social security for that length of time? See [this other SO](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10424/remote-work-in-norway)
2. Would I be required to pay taxes in Norway or can I possibly keep in place my current work arrangements? (possibly same as *question.1*)
3. Provided I have to pay taxes in Norway, what factors should I take into consideration (prioritised) to decide on a new contract type? (see *assumptions.2*)

Comment: You might want to mention if the other EU country is a Nordic country or not, as there are special agreements between the Nordic countries.

Comment: I'm not coming from another Nordic country

Comment: Did you find the answer to your questions?

Comment: @Zarko no, sorry